# Higher dimensional analog of intersection orientation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm working on a 4D renderer and so I'm trying to understand the geometry of higher dimensions. I have been working with a lower dimension analog, intersections across planes, in order to famialiarize myself with the math.

I've come to the conclusion that the intersection of an $N$-simplex with a plane can be an $M$-simplex where $M \in \left[0, N\right]$. That is, the intersection of a line with a plane can be either nothing ($0$-simplex), a point ($1$-simplex), or a line ($2$-simplex). Similarly, the intersection of a triangle with a plane can be nothing, a point, a line, or a triangle. I believe this makes sense for higher dimensions as well.

But I'm currently stuck on the concept of "orientation". It makes sense to me that if a line has orientation (i.e. it is a line pointing *from* $v$ to $u$), then intersection going *into* the plane is **distinct** from intersection coming *out of* the plane. Similarly, if we consider a triangle with orientation (i.e. it has a normal), then intersection with the plane yield an orientation as well. The output of the intersection will have an orientation that is defined by the dot of the plane's normal and the triangle's normal. A positive dot product would have a distinct orientation from a negative dot product.

Is my intuition in this correct? Does this extend to higher dimensions? It would make sense that in 4D space, considering the intersection of a 4-simplex (tetrahedron) with a 3D volume, a tetrahedron would have a normal, and that the dot of that normal with the normal of the volume would define orientation.

But what about the intersection of a triangle with a volume in 4D space? A triangle spans a 2D plane, so there is a rank 2 nullspace, and therefore the "normal" must be a 2D vector. Does this mean that the "orientation" must be defined by *two* scalars? If we take this to be true, then it means that our previous definition of the orientation of a line intersecting with a plane is wrong, since the line also has a rank 2 null space in 3D space.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm now wondering if orientation is instead related to determinant of the mapping of basis vectors. Let me elaborate:

Suppose in 3D space we are intersecting a line with a plane. The line has a rank 2 null space, and the plane has a rank 1 null space.

Picking a particular set of basis vectors for the null space of the line determines the "orientation" of the line. In 3D space, we understand that the sign of the dot of the cross product of the two basis vectors with the line itself is it's orientation. This is because if we pick two points on the line, $u$ and $v$, then the space spanned by $u-v$ and the two basis vectors $b_1$ and $b_2$ -- $\mathrm{span} \left\{b_1, b_2, u-v \right\}$ -- is distinct from $\mathrm{span} \left\{b_1, b_2, v-u \right\}$ in the sense that any change of basis matrix $\mathcal{B}$ would have a negative determinant. Given the same two lines, we can check if their orientation is the same by whether or not we can transform one into the other with positive determinant.

Similarly, in 3D space, a plane has a rank 1 orientation. And the choice of basis vector for this rank 1 normal and the plane defines an orientation which is distinct from if the normal was opposite.

Then we can define the orientation of the intersection by whether or not there exists a change of basis matrix $\mathcal{B}$ from the space defined by the line and its choice of basis for its null space, and the plane and its choice of basis. Bam!

So in 4D space, I suppose a tri would therefore have an orientation defined by a 2D subspace, whether or not the tri and the volume are oriented in the same direction is defined similarly.

**Edit**

Bah, I realized this is still not helpful. Because if we have a line going *into* a plane and a line coming *out* of a plane, we can still have the "orientation of the intersection" be positive simply by rotating the line around intead of flipping it's orientation. So it still doesn't give us a good definition.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).